# Convert table data to tree data JSON format (parent, child) d3.js dynamically?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to visualize table data as tree data in d3.js

My input table data is

[image]

But i want tree data as:

[{"name":"SU1",
       "children":[{
            "name":"DU1",
                "children":[{"name":"ST1"},{"name":"ST2"}]},
                     {"name":"DU2",
                              "children":[]}]},
                                   {"name":"SU2","children":[{
                                       "name":"DU3",
                                           "children":[{"name":"ST3"}]},
                                                   {"name":"SU3","children":[]}]}]

Here my logic is if data value is null there shouldn't be any children for that node.

I have a code here in stack overflow it self but not working for my logic
where do I change the logic such that i wont get the children for null values.

Below is the link for the code what I have tried...

[How to convert Data table to tree json format dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53313396/how-to-convert-data-table-to-tree-json-format-dynamically/53315835#53315835)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you post the input data and also what you have tried?

Comment: var table =  [
      ['SU1', 'DU1', 'ST1'],
      ['SU1', 'DU1', 'ST2'],
      ['SU1', 'DU2', null],
      ['SU2', 'DU3', 'ST3'],
      ['SU3', null, null]
    ] ;
Above is my input data.
Below is the code what i have tried
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53313396/how-to-convert-data-table-to-tree-json-format-dynamically/53315835#53315835

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `forEach` with `reduce` methods to loop your data and build the nested data structure where you also check if the current element is either last node in the tree or if the value is null and then not add the children property.

```js
const data = [
  ['SU1', 'DU1', 'ST1'],
  ['SU1', 'DU1', 'ST2'],
  ['SU1', 'DU2', null],
  ['SU2', 'DU3', 'ST3'],
  ['SU3', null, null]
];


const result = []
const tree = {result}

data.forEach(a => {
  a.reduce((r, name, i, arr) => {
    if (!r[name]) {
      const obj = {name}
      r[name] = {result: []}

      if (arr[i + 1] && name != null) {
        obj.children = r[name].result
      }

      r.result.push(obj)
    }

    return r[name]
  }, tree)
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Export your table to CSV and use a D3 parser

https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv

Answer (score 0):

```
    var test = new function() {

        var table =  [
          ['SU1', 'DU1', 'ST1'],
          ['SU1', 'DU1', 'ST2'],
          ['SU1', 'DU2', null],
          ['SU2', 'DU3', 'ST3'],
          ['SU3', null, null]
        ] ;
           var res = [];

        this.init = function() {
          for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            var curRow = table[i];
            test.myAddFun(res, curRow, 0);
          }
         console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
          return res;
        };

        this.myAddFun = function(_res, arr, startIndex) {
          var addedToJSON = false;
          for (var i = 0; i < _res.length; i++) {
            var curJSON = _res[i];
           console.log(arr[startIndex])
            if ( curJSON['name'] == arr[startIndex]) {
              if (startIndex < arr.length - 1) {
                if(arr[startIndex+1]!=null)
                test.myAddFun(curJSON['children'], arr, startIndex + 1);
              }
              addedToJSON = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          if (addedToJSON) {
            return;
          }
          var curJSON:any = {};
          if(arr[startIndex]!=null)
          curJSON['name'] = arr[startIndex];

          if (startIndex < arr.length - 1) {
            curJSON['children'] = [];
            if(arr[startIndex+1]!=null)
            test.myAddFun(curJSON['children'], arr, startIndex + 1);

        }
          _res.push(curJSON);
          return;
        };

      };
      test.init();
```